# What are the required C3P0 settings for Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, c3p0

I use Hibernate 4.3.0 together with MySQL and Tomcat. All required libraries are in classpath and here's a `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">false</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

<property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>

<!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3000</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
```

With the above settings, after 20 connections to database application is not connecting anymore, and I did't find in application logs relating info to this behaviour.

Does anyone knows what is wrong, and how I can setup c3p0 and hibernate correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings are fine. The reason for running out of connections is because connections are not properly released.

Make sure you:

- commit the transaction on success
- rollback transaction on failure
- close your Hibernate session after you're done with it:

So, this is how you should operate a Hibernate session, in case you don't have Spring to handle transaction/session management on your behalf:

```
Session session = factory.openSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try {
   tx = session.beginTransaction();       
   ...
   tx.commit();
}
catch (Exception e) {
   if (tx!=null) tx.rollback(); 
}finally {
   session.close();
}
```

Comment: This happens on operations not requiring transactions as i understand.
I changed my code to close factory (and session objects):
`SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session hSession = factory.openSession();
Criteria count = hSession.createCriteria(UserTable.class);
count.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
long total = (long) count.uniqueResult();
hSession.close();
factory.close();`
But result is the same as before.

Comment: You only need to close the session factory when the app closes, because it's an expensive object to create on each method call. Try what I suggested.